# Как убрать отступ от верхнего края браузера?

Tags: html, css

У меня не получается убрать отступ от верхнего края страницы :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page-header {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Выпускники ФТИ</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="page-header">
        <p>Graduate</p>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Задал отступ в body равный нулю - убрало только небольшой кусочек справа. Пробовал задавать `padding` и `margin` для body и для header, но ничего не меняется. Подскажите, что нужно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У элемента `p` дефолтные значения `margin-top: 16px; margin-bottom: 16px;`

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю к ответу сверху.

В дальнейшем, чтобы каждый раз не прописывать все в ручную, хорошей практикой считается добавление reset.css или normalize.css:

> https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css
>
> https://github.com/jasonkarns/css-reset

Подробнее можете прочитать [тут](https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/64-about-normalize-css) и [тут](https://habr.com/post/45296/)